# concurrentHashMap putIfAbsent method functionality

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I am a newbie to the world of Java and exploring the `concurrentHashMap`, while exploring the `concurrentHashMap` API , I discover the `putifAbsent()` method

```
public V putIfAbsent(K paramK, V paramV)
  {
    if (paramV == null)
      throw new NullPointerException();
    int i = hash(paramK.hashCode());
    return segmentFor(i).put(paramK, i, paramV, true);
  }
```

Now please advise what is it functionality and when do we practically require it , if possible please explain with a small simple example.

Comment: take a look that is `segmentFor(i)` and how does the method `put(paramK, i, paramV, true)` work. I guess that `true` is something worth to look at.

Answer (score 19):

A `ConcurrentHashMap` is designed so that it can be used by a large number of concurrent `Thread`s.

Now, if you used the methods provided by the standard `Map` interface you would probably write something like this

```
  if(!map.containsKey("something")) {
      map.put("something", "a value");
  }
```

This looks good and seems to do the job but, **it is not thread safe**. So you would then think, "Ah, but I know about the `synchronized` keyword" and change it to this

```
  synchronized(map) {
      if(!map.containsKey("something")) {
          map.put("something", "a value");
      }
  }
```

Which fixes the issue.

Now what you have done is *locked the entire map* for *both read and write* while you check if the key exists and then add it to the map.

This is a very crude solution. Now you could implement your own solution with double checked locks and re-locking on the key etc. but that is *a lot* of *very complicated* code that is very prone to bugs.

So, instead you use the solution provided by the JDK.

The `ConcurrentHashMap` is a clever implementation that divides the `Map` into regions and locks them individually so that you can have concurrent, thread safe, reads and writes of the map without external locking.

Like all other methods in the implementation `putIfAbsent` locks the key's region and not the whole `Map` and therefore allows other things to go on in other regions in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap is used when several threads may access the same map concurrently. In that case, implementing putIfAbsent() manually, like below, is not acceptable:

```
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

Indeed, two threads might execute the above block in parallel and enter in a race condition, where both first test if the key is absent, and then both put their own value in the map, breaking the invariants of the program.

The ConcurrentHashMap thus provides the `putIfAbsent()` operation which makes sure this is done in an atomic way, avoiding the race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine we need a cache of lazy-initialized named singleton beans. Below is a ConcurrentHashMap based lock-free implementation:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

<T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> cls) throws Exception {
    T b1 = (T) map.get(name);
    if (b1 != null) {
        return b1;
    }
    b1 = cls.newInstance();
    T b2 = (T) map.putIfAbsent(name, b1);
    if (b2 != null) {
        return b2;
    }
    return b1;
}
```

Note that it solves the same problem as double-checked locking but with no locking.