# Concurrency and Concurrent Data Structures

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, executor

I am practicing a little bit of concurrency.

```
public class WordOccurrencesBigFile {
    private String words;

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Pair<String, Integer>> wordOccurrencesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public WordOccurrencesBigFile(String wordsLine) {
        this.words = wordsLine;
    }

    public void processWords() {
        parseWordsLines();

        printOrderAlphabetically();
        printOrderByCount();
        printByInsertionOrder();
    }

    private void parseWordsLines() {
        String[] wordsLinesArray = words.split("\n");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for(String wordsLine: wordsLinesArray) {
            executor.execute(() -> parseWords(wordsLine));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }

    private void parseWords(String wordsLine) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Start.");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Processing line: '" + wordsLine + "'");
        String[] wordsArray = wordsLine.split(" ");

        synchronized(this){
            for (String word : wordsArray) {
                Pair<String, Integer> pair = null;
                if (!wordOccurrencesMap.containsKey(word)) {
                    pair = new Pair<>(word, 1);
                    //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Creating Pair: " + pair);
                } else {
                    pair = wordOccurrencesMap.get(word);
                    pair.setValue(pair.getValue() + 1);
                    //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Updating Pair: " + pair);
                }

                wordOccurrencesMap.put(word, pair);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " End.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wordsLines = "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa\n"+
            "bb cc aa ccc bb cc cc aa";

        WordOccurrencesBigFile wordOccurrences = new 
        WordOccurrencesBigFile(wordsLines);
        wordOccurrences.processWords();
}
```

}

On the parseWordsLines an ExecutorService is created with a pool of 5 threads, and the WordOccurrencesBigFile class is instantiated with String with multiple lines created by "\n". The purpose is to have each line being processed by a different threads and insert on the Map the count of unique words.

I was expecting that by using ConcurrentHashMap would be sufficient to deal with the fact i have multiple threads reading and writing to the map. But i am getting different counts most of the times i execute the class. (Strangely is mainly for the "bb" word.

But adding the synchronized(this) the problem is fixed.

Can someone explain me why this behavior, the best way to approach this problem, and should i pass "this" to the synchronized block or the object that is being access by the threads?

Thank you very much.

Comment: your counter increments are not atomic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe, which can make sure every single operation is thread safe.

But these operations are not atomic:

```
            if (!wordOccurrencesMap.containsKey(word)) {
                pair = new Pair<>(word, 1);
                //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Creating Pair: " + pair);
            } else {
                pair = wordOccurrencesMap.get(word);
                pair.setValue(pair.getValue() + 1);
                //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Updating Pair: " + pair);
            }

            wordOccurrencesMap.put(word, pair);
```

You can use an single operation instead:

```
wordOccurrencesMap.compute(word,
        (s, pair) -> pair == null ?
                new Pair<>(word, 1) : pair.setValue(pair.getValue() + 1));
```

Comment: But note that while `compute` is atomic, the `Pair` has to be thread safe, as querying its value *after* retrieving it via `ConcurrentHashMap.get` may happen concurrently to some `setValue` call. It’s likely better to use  `wordOccurrencesMap.merge(word, new Pair<>(word, 1), (p,q) -> new Pair<>(p.getKey(), p.getValue()+q.getValue()));` which will never modify an existing `Pair` instance, hence, allows to safely query them after retrieval without additional measures. It would also work well with an immutable `Pair` type.

Comment: But why repeating the key in a `Pair` instance at all? When using `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> wordOccurrencesMap`, we can simply update the word count via `wordOccurrencesMap..merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);` and be safe, as `Integer` objects are immutable. Then, e.g. `wordOccurrencesMap.forEach((word,count) -> …);`, allows to process word/count pairs.

Comment: @Holger In this case, suppose the `pair` is only accessed via `wordOccurrencesMap.compute`, it's guranteed to be thread safe. right?

Comment: That’s right. If it is only processed inside the atomic operations offered by the `ConcurrentHashMap`, it’s safe. However, developers rarely want a write-only storage, hence, there will be a time when they want to query the result contents and that’s where it becomes tricky…

Comment: @Holger yeah. From code the OP post, it seems he does not query the result util `while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }`.  So I guess it's ok even if Pair is not thread safe just in this case.

Comment: Yes, using an external thread safe condition that precludes any concurrent access (due to finishing all jobs), allows to query the result. But you won’t see this when looking at the map access which uses a different mechanism for thread safety. So you have to do a good job at documenting such a code, to be sure that the next developer doesn’t break it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, adding `synchronized(this)` fixes the problem, but you will lose all benefits from the multi threading and parallelization.

What you need is the `computeIfAbsent` method of `ConcurrentMap`. So the body of your `for` loop will transform to

```
Pair<String, Integer> pair = wordOccurrencesMap.computeIfAbsent(word, w -> new Pair<>(w, 0));
synchronized(pair) {
    pair.setValue(pair.getValue()+1);
}
```

Now you can omit your `synchronized(this)` block.

EDIT: But you must ensure that not another thread can call pair.getValue() when the first thread calls pair.setValue() as the comments remarked.

Comment: …and you think `pair.setValue(pair.getValue()+1);` is thread safe?

Comment: You've been right. I put a ``synchronized(pair)`` around the setValue and getValue. Now it should work. Another approach would be to use an AtomicInteger to store the number of word occurrences

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas mentioned in the comment you counter increments are not atomic, it means that,

```
    if (!wordOccurrencesMap.containsKey(word)) {
------>// two threads can enter in this block and results will be different.

        pair = new Pair<>(word, 1);
        //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Creating Pair: " + pair);
    }
```

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850803/concurrent-hashmap-putifabsent-method-functionality) for more information as it explains the same issue in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to add my two cents to the "best way to approach this problem" part of the question:

- You have a printByInsertionOrder() method. You won't be able to maintain this order if you process your text in parallel whithout keeping some kind of positional data.
- You will encounter a whole world of troubles with your split pattern using 
  `wordsLine.split(" ")` if you get text written by humans. I suggest using `"[^\\p{L}0-9]+"` instead, which matches "at least one character not beeing a unicode letter or a digit". The `\p{L}` is especially powerful in that it will also match diacriticals like é, è or Ö.

My suggestion, is to avoid explicit concurrency whenever possible, and focus on functional idioms, with something like this :

```
public class SplitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "On the parseWordsLines an ExecutorService is created with a pool of 5 \n threads, and the WordOccurrencesBigFile class is instantiated with String with multiple lines created by \"\\n\". The purpose is to have each line being processed by a different threads and insert on the Map the count of unique words.";
        List<Entry<String, Point>> allWordsWithPositions = splitLines(text).entrySet().stream()
                .parallel()
                .flatMap(SplitTest::splitWordToStream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        allWordsWithPositions.forEach(w -> System.out.println(w.getKey() + ":" + w.getValue()));
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> splitLines(String text) {
        String[] split = text.split("\n");
        HashMap<String, Integer> lineMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
            lineMap.put(split[i], i);
        }
        return lineMap;
    }

    private static Stream<Entry<String, Point>> splitWordToStream(Entry<String, Integer> lineEntry) {
        return splitWords(lineEntry.getValue(), lineEntry.getKey()).entrySet().stream();
    }

    private static Map<String, Point> splitWords(Integer lineNumber, String line) {
        String[] split = line.split("[^\\p{L}0-9]+");
        HashMap<String, Point> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; ++i) {
            wordMap.put(split[i], new Point(i, lineNumber));
        }
        return wordMap;
    }
}
```

Now you have a list with all the word properly split, and their position in the text. And done in parallel without headache. You just have to post-process the result to get all the representations you need :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Actually this was an exercise presented to me on an job interview, and the concurrency question was an extra one, for a big file scenario. With no concurrency, a LinkedHashMap can be used to keep the insertion order.

Comment: You're welcome. You should have a look at Files.lines as well then. For big files, you can read lines lazily, and not overload your RAM.